# Retrieving log message within curly braces using Regex with Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse some logs which return some responses in a key-pair format. I only want they value contained by the last key-pair (Rs: {".."}). The information I want are enclosed inside the curly braces.

What I have done is to use regex to match anything inside the curly braces like this:

```
import re

log = '2016-10-13 17:04:50 - info - uri:"GET x/y/z" ip:1.1.1.1 Rs:{"data": "blah blah"}'

text = re.compile("Rs\:{(.*)\}").search(log).group(1)
print (text)

>>> "data": "blah blah"

# Desired results
>>> {"data": "blah blah"}
```

However there are some issues doing it this way:

1. I also wanted the starting curly braces and closing curly braces.
2. This method doesn't work if there other opening ("{") or closing ("}:) curly braces before or inside the Rs values.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: First, fix the code, you are missing `'` on the `log` line. Then, use `r"Rs:({[^}]*})"` regex. Or please clarify: do you want a dictionary as output?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew just the entire line starting from {..} is all I need. No need for dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need two things: re-adjust the first capturing group boundaries to include curly braces, and use a lazy version of `.*` (in case there are multiple values in the string). I also recommend checking if there is a match first  if you are using `re.search`, or just use `re.findall`

```
import re
log = '2016-10-13 17:04:50 - info - uri:"GET x/y/z" ip:1.1.1.1 Rs:{"data": "blah blah"}'
text = re.compile(r"Rs:({[^}]*})").search(log)
if text:
    print (text.group(1))
# or
print(re.findall(r"Rs:({[^}]*})", log))
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/XW2ots)

**Pattern details**:

- `Rs:` - a whole word `Rs` and a `:`
- `({[^}]*})` - Group 1 capturing

  - `{` - a literal `{`
  - `[^}]*` - 0+ chars other than `}` (see [more details on *Negated Character Classes* here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated))
  - `}` -  a literal `}`.

Answer (score 1):

The first part is easy: just move the capturing parens out a little bit use this as your regex:

```
"Rs:(\{.*\})"
```

The other problem is more complicated - if you want the rest of the line (starting at `{`), then

```
r'Rs:(\{.*)\Z'
```

would get you what you want.